# When casting return from new int[10][3] to int** pointer, the program using it outputs : Segmentation fault: 11?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Why this program outputs: ***Segmentation fault: 11***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int **a = (int**)new int[10][3];
    a[0][0] = 1; a[0][1] = 2; a[0][2] = 3;
    cout << a[0][0] << "," << a[0][1] << "," << a[0][2];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Go to the whiteboard and write 100 times: "An array is not a pointer".

Comment: also take a look at [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You may find them easier to manage and pass around than a 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this declaration

```
int **a = (int**)new int[10][3];
```

to

```
int ( *a )[3] = new int[10][3];
```

Otherwise pointers `int **` and `int ( *a )[3]` returned by the operator new are incompatible.

The problem is that in expression `a[0]` when `a` has type `int **` the compiler tries to read the allocated non-initialized memory as a valid value of pointer of type `int *`.

Also you should delete the pointer at the end of the program

```
delete [] a;
```

Another approach is the following

```
int **a = new int * [10];

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) a[i] = new int[3];
```

In this case the allocated memory is freed the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) delete [] a[i];
delete [] a;
```